# Entity Framework Single Bit Query Return Value to Boolean

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query code to check if an engineer is allowed to do something from a database

```
 var isAllowed = context.Engineers
                 .Where(b => b.Engineer1 == Environment.UserName)
                  .Select(x => new { x.IsAllowed }).First();
```

I try to use isAllowed in an IF statement

```
   if (isAllowed)
                {
                 ...do something
                }
```

The error:

[image]

If I use ToString() then I see

[image]

To avoid using  `ToString=="{IsAllowed = False}"`, how should I fix this error?

Comment: The way you have it you'd want `if(isAllowed.IsAllowed)`

Comment: @K_foxer9 Actually that returns the first item where `IsAllowed` is true, which in this case there would be none that match and it would result in an exception.

Comment: @juharr's right.  My dumb mistake. `First(x => x.IsAllowed)` is equivalent to `.Where(x => x.IsAllowed).First()`, which is not what OP wanted at all.  `.Select(x => x.IsSelected).First()` is what was needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an anonymous type. I don't think you need it:

```
var isAllowed = context.Engineers
                       .Where(b => b.Engineer1 == Environment.UserName)
                       .First().IsAllowed;
```

If you want to use it for some reason, you can though:

```
if (isAllowed.IsAllowed)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this is my first entity framework application and there are many thing news to learn (I am also lack of C# knowledge which I am catching up with some online tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

The result of `Select(x => new { x.IsAllowed }).First()` is an object of anonymous type with a single field called `IsAllowed`. You can access it with a dot expression, but it does not look nice:

```
if (isAllowed.IsAllowed) { // <<== This reads as a repetition
    ...
}
```

If you want a direct `bool`, remove `new`:

```
Select(x => x.IsAllowed).First()
```

Comment: Thanks - now I know how to handle this type of problems.